# Is there a CorePlot sample project for iOS 6.1 available somewhere?

Tags: core-plot, ios6.1

CorePlot looks like the best library going for the iPad apps I'm looking into, but I've been fighting all day just to get it to compile in an OS 6.1 project set to use Core Date, ARC, and unit tests.

I want to use those specs, but I'm starting fresh, with no other code that needs salvaged, so it occurred to me that rather than fight through the tutorials that don't address installation in ARC; and through the fixes for ARC that never seem to get me all the way to compile-able; that I could easily take any bare-bones project with those basic specs and start bringing in the simpler additions I've already figured out.

Anything like that out there?

Comment: Have you considered using CorePlot compiled without ARC and just linking it to your ARC-compiled apps?   That's how we've used CorePlot with ARC.  I didn't have any trouble getting it to compile with a 6.1 target as a sub-project of my own project (which uses ARC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the *CPTTestApp* example apps for both Mac and iOS have been converted to use ARC. This was done after the 1.1 release, so at the moment you'll need to pull the latest code with Mercurial to see the changes.

Since the 1.0 release, no changes to the Core Plot project is required to use it in an app that uses ARC. The Core Plot header files will compile under all supported SDKs with and without ARC. Include the Core Plot static library in your app, either the pre-compiled version or one built as a dependent project, and it will link and run just fine.

Core Plot does not use ARC internally because it still supports older systems that cannot use it. It will be updated when the minimum supported system is increased to one that supports ARC on both Mac and iOS.